# How do I go about creating two objects that are tied to each other by a foreign key in one form/view in django?

Tags: django

So, I have a messaging component of an app I am creating. There is a `Conversation` object, which has a ManyToMany field to user. Then, there is the actual `InsantMessage` object, which has a sender field to user, textfield and another field called `receiver` that is a foreign key to my conversation object. Now what I am attempting to do is to create a link underneath another user's profile, and then pass their pk in that link to my view which will check to first see if their already exists a conversation object with request.user and the other user, and if so, will create a message object and then automatically pass in the Convo object pk for the foreign key field `conversation` in my Message object.  Now, I think I have the basic understanding of how to do this, perhaps just using an if statement and a nested form. But, where I'm stuck in is, how do I get the conversation pk to automatically pass? And how would if the conversation object is being created, how can I get request.user/other user to be automatically put in the conversation object? Even if you don't want to write out my code, just point me in the right direction of where to look. I've been stuck on this problem for a couple days now.

**models.py**

```
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))



class Conversation(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)




class InstantMessage(models.Model):


    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'senderr',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message

    #tests to see if messages are exclusive between sender, receiver (won't work with new model)
    @classmethod
    def find_messages_exclusive_to_profile(cls,sender,receiver):
        #members = receiver AND sender, not receiver or sender 
        exclusive_conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(members= receiver ).filter(members= sender)


        exclusive_messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(receiver__in=exclusive_conversations)

        return exclusive_messages
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):

    context = {'random_profiles': Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).order_by('?')[:3]}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/home.html',context)


def profiles(request):
    "Shows a list of profiles that have been created"
    profiles = Profile.objects.order_by('date_joined')
    context = {'profiles' : profiles}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/profiles.html',context)


def profile(request, profile_id):
    """show a single profile"""
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)
    context = {'profile' : profile}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/profile.html', context)



# Below is related to users


def logout_view(request):
    """Log out the user """
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dating_app:home'))


def register(request, profile_id):
    user =User.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    user.profile.bio = 'fjfjfjjf'
    user.save()


def register(request):
    #Register a new user
    context = {}

    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            description = form.cleaned_data.get("description")
            photo = form.cleaned_data.get("photo")
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            profile = authenticate(username=username,email=email,description=description, photo=photo, password=raw_password)
            login(request, profile)
            return redirect ('dating_app:home')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    else: #get request 
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'dating_app/register.html', context)



def update_account(request, profile_id):
    #Edit an existing profile 
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)
    update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #Initial request; prefil form with current entry
        update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile)
    else:
        #POST data submitted;process data. 
        update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if update_form.is_valid():
            update_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dating_app:profile', args=[profile.id]))

    context = {'profile' : profile, 'update_form' : update_form}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/update.html', context)



#matching
def mingle(request):



    try:
        profile = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
    except IndexError:
        profile = None
        print(Profile.username)
    try:

        description = request.user.description
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        create = Profile.objects.get_or_create(request.user)
        return redirect('profile')

    match = request.user.matches.all()
    context = dict(profile = profile, match = match)    
    return render(request, 'dating_app/mingle.html', context)



@login_required
def nice(request, profile_id):

    return create_vote(request, profile_id, True)

@login_required
def nope(request, profile_id):
    return create_vote(request, profile_id, False)





def create_vote(request, profile_id, vote):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=profile_id)


    UserVote.objects.create(
        user=profile,
        voter=request.user,
        vote=vote
    )
    other = UserVote.objects.filter(
        voter=profile,
        user=request.user,
        vote=True
    )
    if vote and other.exists():
        profile.matches.add(request.user)
        request.user.matches.add(profile)
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')



def view_matches(request,profile_id):
    match = request.user.matches.all()
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)

    context = {'match' : match, 'profile' : profile}

    return render(request, 'dating_app/matches.html', context)



#form
def instant_message(request, receiver_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InstantMessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.sender = request.user
            form.instance.receiver = get_object_or_404(get_user_mode(), pk=receiver_id)
            form.save()
            return redirect('dating_app:home')
    else:
        form = InstantMessageForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/instant_message_form.html',context)



def messages(request, profile_id):


    other_user = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)

    exclusive_conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(members= request.user ).filter(members= other_user)
    messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(receiver__in=exclusive_conversations)

    context = {'messages' : messages, 'other_user' : other_user}

    return render(request, 'dating_app/messages.html', context)



def conversations(request,profile_id):




    conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(
        members=profile_id
    ).annotate(
        last_message=Max('instantmessage__date')
    ).prefetch_related('members').order_by(
        '-last_message'
    )



    return render(request, 'dating_app/conversations.html', {'conversations':conversations,})
```